# Unset session after some time

Tags: php, session, background

I am building a online ticket booking site . In this I am doing the following things : The user searches the bus with their seat numbers . The database is updated with the seat numbers with `temp_seat_book = 'Y'` . If he books the ticket paying money his status will be updated to `final_ticket_book = 'Y'` . Now I want to delete the field whose `temp_seat_book = 'Y'` but 
`final_ticket_book = 'N'` . For this I need to delete the session_ids which is more than 10minutes old and `final_ticket_book = 'N'`. So how I can implement the background job?

Comment: just have a timestamp and check it?

Comment: wouldn't a single db field of 'seat_status' with contains one of the 3 statuses be easier.

Comment: may You found your answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of doing a search for files (which involves more i/o ) etc,
What is a session cookie: [Session Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie)
A better way is to store a time stamp of the 'most recent activity' in the $_SESSION variable.
And updating the session data on every request (including the automated periodic ajax calls if any).

Lets say you want to unset the session after 10 minutes,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['most_recent_activity']) && 
    (time() -   $_SESSION['most_recent_activity'] > 600)) {

 //600 seconds = 10 minutes
 session_destroy();   
 session_unset();  

 }
 $_SESSION['most_recent_activity'] = time(); // the start of the session.
```

> To avoid attacks like [Session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation): (Session Fixation is an attack that permits an attacker to hijack a valid user session) keep regenerating the session id periodically say for 5 mins (I would suggest to keep the regeneration time as well as session expire time a bit more). A more elaborate list of attacks: [attack list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack).

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
    } 
else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 600) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);    
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  
    }
```

Also, make sure `session.gc-maxlifetime` is set to the maximum expire time you want to use.
You can do this

```
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 600)
```

Or
Set it directly in your php.ini.

and also

[session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) :

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser.
>   But, destroying the session must be taken care at the server-side and not the client-side.
>   Setting the session.cookie_lifetime set to 0 would make the session’s cookie behave the way  a session cookie should i.e. that a session cookie is only valid until the browser is closed.

Although this method is a tad tedious, Its more elegant.

Ah, found the link which I had read a long time ago! : [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Answer (score 3):

Standard PHP sessions are stored in files. You could implement a simple shell script to find any session file which hasn't been touched in 10 minutes:

```
find /path/to/session/dir/* -mmin -10
```

grep can be used to find the session files which have a final_ticket_book='N' value stored in them:

```
grep -l 's:17:"final_ticket_book";s:1:"N";'
```

(the -l flags has grep spit out the names of the files which match).

Combining the two gives you:

```
find /path/to/session/dir -mmin -10|xargs grep -l 's:17:"final_ticket_book";s:1:"N";'|xargs rm -f
```